# Selected item in combobox disappear

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

I using the Material Design xaml:

http://materialdesigninxaml.net/

In the combobox control when I select an item it will fixed on the top and will be removed from the list, an example:

[image]

I've selected the items 2, as you can see in this image:

[image]

the item selected `2` is moved on the top and removed in the list of combobox item, how can I keep the item in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set ComboBoxAssist.ClassicMode to True, like so:

```
<ComboBox materialDesign:ComboBoxAssist.ClassicMode="True">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Apple</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Banana</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Pear</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Orange</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

An example can be found [here](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/f1ed10c3eedd6b23f490a9f07d102c4f8cd4670b/MainDemo.Wpf/TextFields.xaml#L286-L293).

Comment: Thank you very much, is possible also keep the combobox open after selected a item?